# How to align images with autors' names?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I would like to add a picture of the different authors of a document centered above their name.

Here is what I have:
[image: The result I got]
As you can see, `Teacher{I}` and pictures are not align...
**Is there a way to align them, without having to redefine the `and` command as the modification would only be effective to this specific document and not to every file?**

Here is my code :

```
%% PACKAGES
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[compact, explicit]{titlesec}

\title{\sc{High School} \\ \vfill Subject NAME\\ \bf{Document NAME}\\ \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Logo_school.jpeg}\\
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{Teacher.jpg}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{Teacher.jpg}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{Teacher.jpg}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{Teacher.jpg}
\end{figure}
}

\date{October 3, 2023} 
\author{\sc{Teacher1} \and \sc{Teacher2} \and \sc{Teacher3} \and \sc{Teacher4}}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[R]{Subject \\ Document \\ \ }
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\begin{tabular}{|l l}
     \sc{Teacher1} & \sc{Teacher2}  \\
     \sc{Teacher3} & \sc{Teacher4} 
\end{tabular}}
\fancyfoot[C]{Date : 10/03/2023}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\headsep}{2cm}


%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%

\begin{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\begin{titlepage}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vfill
    \textbf{Year} 2023 - 2024 \hfill \textbf{Director:} \sc{Name}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
Test 123

\end{document}
```

Comment: How should TeX know that the pictures and the names are related to each other. You define a figure including multiple images *inside* the `\title`command and in the separate `\author` command some contributors. There is no direct relation between the two commands except that they're both called inside `\maketitle`. Plus, it might not be the best decision to place all this stuff inside `\title`. A better solution would be defining a correct titlepage or edit `\maketitle`. At the moment, its not possible for me to test it. Maybe later or someone else has time to provide an answer...

Comment: @lukeflo I know LaTeX can’t know it’s linked but for now, that’s the best I could achieve. I tried to add the pictures in the ```author{}``` environment but it fails to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, though your code is a bit ... strange in the sense of unbalanced.

Let's go through it.

So you define `\title` and `\author` AND recreate the title page via the `titlepage-environment`. That's a bit of double work, unless you'll need exactly the content of `\title` and `\author` again. It would be enough to enter everything manually within the `titlepage-environment` (that's its purpose).

Within the `\title` you put the 4 images inside a `\figure` float environment ... you don't need that one, and you probably don't want Latex to shift around the 4 images. So I dropped it.

I added `%` at the end of lines. Though it may not be needed within the `\title` variable, I don't know this for sure, it would be needed inside a `\newcommand` with line breaks to avoid unwanted spaces.

For the teachers names I just put them the same way inside the `\title` manually, as you did with the images. That's it. HOWEVER, all this you'd do outisde of `\title` and inside the `titlepage-environment`.

Should you need the 4 names as variables, just define 4 `\newcommand`s and replace all occurances.

So, my changes do work, but better move everything inside of `\begin{titlepage} ... \end{titlepage}` AND call `\maketitle` outside of it (it will ... use the latter for typesetting ...)

[image: result]

```
%% PACKAGES
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[compact, explicit]{titlesec}

\title{\sc{High School} \\ \vfill Subject NAME\\ \bf{Document NAME}\\ \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Logo_school}\\
%\begin{figure}[H]% <<< not needed
    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{Teacher.jpg}\hfill% <<<
    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{Teacher.jpg}\hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{Teacher.jpg}\hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{Teacher.jpg}\\%
%\end{figure}
% ~~~ new ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\sc{Teacher1} \hfill  \sc{Teacher2}  \hfill \sc{Teacher3}  \hfill \sc{Teacher4}%
}

\date{October 3, 2023} 
%\author{\sc{Teacher1} \and \sc{Teacher2} \and \sc{Teacher3} \and \sc{Teacher4}}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}

\fancyhead[R]{Subject \\ Document \\ \ }
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\begin{tabular}{|l l}
     \sc{Teacher1} & \sc{Teacher2}  \\
     \sc{Teacher3} & \sc{Teacher4} 
\end{tabular}}
\fancyfoot[C]{Date : 10/03/2023}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\headsep}{2cm}


%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%

\begin{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\begin{titlepage}
    \maketitle % <<< !!! <<<< move it outside !!!
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vfill
    \textbf{Year} 2023 - 2024 \hfill \textbf{Director:} \sc{Name}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
Test 123

\end{document}
```

Comment: When using not squared image,  they are not centered with the name under. Is there a way to do this ?